# How to group Jekyll pages by the first letter of the title?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm building a Jekyll site that has a page for each topic. I want to create an alphabetically grouped list of links to each page.

For example, if my topic titles are:

- Aardvark
- Beatle
- Catfish
- Cattle

I want to end up with a list of links organised as:

- A

  - Aardvark
- B

  - Beatle
- C

  - Catfish
  - Cattle

So far, I have gotten code that looks like this:

```
{% assign topics_by_letter = 
    site.topics | group_by_expr: "topic", "topic.title | slice: 0, 1" %}

{% for letter in topics_by_letter %}
    <div>
        {{ letter.name }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

`site.topics` is the correct name of the page collection and evaluates as expected.

All topics have a valid `title` label.

Where I am stuck is that `letter.name` evaluates to empty and I just have a list of empty divs. The snippet `{{ page.title | slice: 0, 1 }}` works and gives you back the first letter of the topic title.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try `group_by_exp` instead of `group_by_expr`.

Comment: Huh, that was dumb. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Was a typo, `group_by_expr` should be `group_by_exp`.